# Azure Blob FIles Access and Properties - Can't Set Properties

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to access and set the cache properties of my existing blob files but it 404's when trying to set the properties. It can call FetchAttributes() just fine; but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here:

```
foreach (var b in blobs)
{
    CloudBlobContainer container = bh.GetEntFileContainer(b.Id, true);
    var blobFiles = container.ListBlobs(null, true);
    foreach (var file in blobFiles)
    {
        CloudBlob blob = new CloudBlob(file.Uri);
        try
        {
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            // set cache-control header if necessary
            if (blob.Properties.CacheControl != "max-age=604800, public")
            {
                blob.Properties.CacheControl = "max-age=604800, public";
                blob.SetProperties(); //404 here.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string a = "404, doesn't exist";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (var b in blobModels)
            {
                var cloudBlobContainer = bh.GetEntFileContainer(b.Id, true);
                IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobInfos = cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);
                foreach (var blobInfo in blobInfos)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = (CloudBlockBlob)blobInfo;
                        var blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(blockBlob.Name);
                        blob.FetchAttributes();

                        // set cache-control header if necessary
                        if (blob.Properties.CacheControl != newCacheSettings)
                        {
                            blob.Properties.CacheControl = newCacheSettings;
                            blob.SetProperties();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
```